# Python Error - For and IF NOT in same statement

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I'm using Python 3.5, i am trying to remove NLTK stopWords from my dataset and when i run the a statement which combines both For & IF NOT in one statement i get an error. Searching for the error did not yield any useful results.

Code and error snapshot attached below enter image description here

```
base_data['stemmed_stop_comments'] = [word for word in base_data['stemmed_comments'] if not word in stopWords]
```

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: What is base_data? A `pandas` `DataFrame`?

Comment: Yes, a pandas dataframe!

Comment: The problem is that you are assigning a list to a column of a dataframe but your dimensions don't match (obviously because you are removing stopwords...)

Comment: The rows in the data frame have to stay the same length. Maybe you could replace the stopwords with `None` or `''`...

Comment: Ok, i think i found a solution! @juanpa.arrivillaga was right, i was trying to assign a list to a dataframe. Solved the problem by writing a separate function. Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_stop(sentance):
   removed = [x for x in sentance.split(' ') if x.lower() not in stopWords]
   return ' '.join(removed)

base_data['stemmed_stop_comments'] = base_data.stemmed_comments.apply(lambda x: remove_stop(x))
```

Comment: Add some description, explaining solution.

Answer (score -2):

It seems you don't have key in base_data as 'stemmed_comments'. Use statement like this

```
base_data['stemmed_stop_comments'] = []

if 'stemmed_comments' in base_data:
    base_data['stemmed_stop_comments'] = [word for word in base_data['stemmed_comments'] if not (word in stopWords)]
```

or

```
if 'stemmed_comments' in base_data:
   base_data['stemmed_stop_comments'] = [word for word in base_data['stemmed_comments'] if word not in stopWords]
```

or

```
if 'stemmed_comments' in base_data:
     base_data['stemmed_stop_comments'] = filter(lambda word: word not in stopWords, base_data['stemmed_comments'])
```

Comment: Yes, this is good style advice, the latter especially, but I doubt this is the issue.

Comment: This is definitely not the problem. `not word in stopwords` is _not_ interpreted as `(not word) in stopwords`

Comment: Yes, you are right, i did try the different style combinations, but the error do not go away!

Comment: ok then before using this base_data['stemmed_comments'] have a check of 'stemmed_comments' in base_data

Comment: updating My answer

Comment: What exactly you want me to check for? The 3rd suggestion you made ran error free but returns funny data                                                          ** <filter object at 0x000001D022DD1198>**

Comment: @AnandVenu i want you to check base_data object/structure data, and 3rd suggestion returns object that you need to iterate like for i in 3rdSuggestion: and print i